# Async function returns a pending promise even though "await" is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I was following an async/await tutorial. Even though I'm copying the code 1:1, it doesn't work as intended.

Here's a function, it accepts a fruit name as a parameter and returns a number accordingly. It's asynchronous, so it should return a promise.

```
const getFruit = async(name) => {
const fruits = {
    pineapple: 1,
    apple: 2,
    strawberry: 3
}

    return fruits[name]
}
```

Works as intended, doing `getFruit("apple").then(result => console.log(result))` returns 2.

Afterwards, I have the second function that runs the `getFruit` function twice to get two numbers, awaits the results and then combines them. In theory.

```
const makeSmoothie = async() => {
    const a = await getFruit("apple")
    const b = await getFruit("strawberry")
    const smoothie = [a, b]

    return smoothie
}
```

But in reality, `console.log(makeSmoothie())` then returns a `Promise { <pending> }`. Why?

Also, I'm aware that I'm actually unnecessarily preventing the script from getting the value `b` until `a` is retrieved. It just looks simpler this way.  Assigning both values and then doing `const smoothie = await Promise.all([a, b])` doesn't work, either. Same results.

Comment: `async` functions *always* return a promise (by specification).

Comment: Use then with return of the function